# Change owner of android app from a person to a company, and keep same dev and login

Tags: android, authentication, administrator, owner

If I am the personal owner and main dev of an android app, and I  decide to build a company to manage that app. How can I manage this on android? I don't want to create a new dev account. I want to keep the same login to android management, keep the same app ratings and reviews, but change the name of the owner to my new company. Does anyone knows if this is possible and how?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @Lonesomezorro Did you have a chance to check my answer below? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73336001/2271651

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the **Developer page** section of the Google Play dev console and change the Developer name, address, and so on.

[image]